# How do I pull data from 30 months ago and prior?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to automate my code so that it can only pull data from 30 months ago, since that is around when a data set is fully complete for the year. So for example, when it is July 1st, 2019, the code should pull from January 1st 2017 which is 30 months prior. I thought that the code I wrote would do this, but there are still instances of 2018 records showing up. Am I properly using this dateadd function?

```
select *
from table
where month(period_end) <= month(dateadd(month, -30, getdate()))
```

This runs fine, but 2018 records are still showing up when I should only see 2017 and before.

Comment: Hello! This question does not show research effort.

Comment: `month()` will extract *only the month* from the date. If you care about the entire date, no need to wrap it in `month(...)`.

Comment: `dateadd(month, -30, getdate())` is `2016-12-18` so this wouldn't show 2017 either.

Comment: @JNevill per OP's scenario, if you ran the query on July 1st, it would return 2017-01-01.  `SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -30, '20190701')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify it, you don't need month():

```
where period_end <= dateadd(month, -30, getdate())
```

`dateadd(month, -30, getdate())` returns the maximum date you want `period_end` to compare to.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the use of the `MONTH()` function -- that returns a number, 1-12, so you're actually comparing the month number of `period_end` against the month number 30 months ago. Replace your WHERE with

```
WHERE period_end <= DATEADD(MONTH, -30, GETDATE())
```